# SQL get number of hours on previous rows

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a query that extracts information about a store opening and close time. This is the resultset:

```
RTL_LOC_ID TRANS_TYPCODE                  BEGIN_DATETIME            
---------- ------------------------------ ---------------------------
      2390 WORKSTATION_OPEN               14.10.01 09:53:43,121000000 
      2390 WORKSTATION_CLOSE              14.10.01 23:51:49,729000000 
      2390 WORKSTATION_OPEN               14.10.02 09:57:47,768000000 
      2390 WORKSTATION_CLOSE              14.10.02 23:47:00,120000000 
      2390 WORKSTATION_OPEN               14.10.03 09:47:38,949000000 
      2390 WORKSTATION_CLOSE              14.10.03 23:45:42,602000000
```

6 rows selected

This is the query:

```
SELECT RTL_LOC_ID,TRANS_TYPCODE, BEGIN_DATETIME
FROM TRN_TRANS
WHERE(trans_typcode = 'WORKSTATION_OPEN' OR trans_typcode='WORKSTATION_CLOSE')
AND BUSINESS_DATE BETWEEN '14.10.01 00:00:00' AND '14.10.03 00:00:00'
ORDER BY BUSINESS_DATE, BEGIN_DATETIME ASC;
```

So I need to calculate the number of hours between the opening and closing of the store and place that value into a new column. I would also like to put the result for the day in the same row instead of two separate lines for each day.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes **MySQL** since the question was not tagged with Oracle to begin with. I'm leaving this answer here, since it might inspire someone with Oracle skills toward a solution...

Assuming a location always opens before it closes, a quick and dirty solution could look like this:

```
SELECT RTL_LOC_ID, DATE(BUSINESS_DATE), 
    MIN(BUSINESS_DATE) AS [OpenTime],
    MAX(BUSINESS_DATE) AS [CloseTime]
FROM 
    TRN_TRANS
WHERE(trans_typcode = 'WORKSTATION_OPEN' OR trans_typcode='WORKSTATION_CLOSE')
AND BUSINESS_DATE BETWEEN '14.10.01 00:00:00' AND '14.10.03 00:00:00'
GROUP BY RTL_LOC_ID, DATE(BUSINESS_DATE)
ORDER BY DATE(BUSINESS_DATE)
```

Or if you want to be pedantic:

```
SELECT RTL_LOC_ID, DATE(BUSINESS_DATE), 
    MAX(CASE trans_typcode WHEN 'WORKSTATION_OPEN' THEN BUSINESS_DATE ELSE NULL END) AS [OpenTime],
    MAX(CASE trans_typcode WHEN 'WORKSTATION_CLOSE' THEN BUSINESS_DATE ELSE NULL END) AS [CloseTime],
FROM
    -- rest of query same as above --
```

Comment: Hello Dan. Trying to execute your query results in the following SQL error: SQL Error: ORA-00923: palavra chave FROM não foi encontrada onde se esperava
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: You didn't specify that you're using Oracle. You should add an `oracle` tag to your question. I assumed MySql since you had the `mysqli` tag...

Comment: Sorry Dan you are right. I am working with Oracle SQL Developer. Added the tag now

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT
TRN_TRANS.RTL_LOC_ID,
DATE_FORMAT(BEGIN_DATETIME ,'%Y-%m-%d') AS _date,
TIMEDIFF(closing_time.BEGIN_DATETIME , opening_time.BEGIN_DATETIME ) AS _hours
FROM TRN_TRANS

INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT RTL_LOC_ID, BEGIN_DATETIME, DATE_FORMAT(BEGIN_DATETIME ,'%Y-%m-%d') as _date
        FROM TRN_TRANS
        WHERE TRANS_TYPCODE = 'WORKSTATION_OPEN'
    ) AS opening_time
ON 
TRN_TRANS.RTL_LOC_ID = opening_time.RTL_LOC_ID
AND
DATE_FORMAT(TRN_TRANS.BEGIN_DATETIME ,'%Y-%m-%d') = opening_time._date


INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT RTL_LOC_ID, BEGIN_DATETIME, DATE_FORMAT(BEGIN_DATETIME ,'%Y-%m-%d') as _date
            FROM TRN_TRANS
            WHERE TRANS_TYPCODE = 'WORKSTATION_CLOSE'
        ) AS closing_time
ON
TRN_TRANS.RTL_LOC_ID = closing_time.RTL_LOC_ID
AND
DATE_FORMAT(TRN_TRANS.BEGIN_DATETIME ,'%Y-%m-%d') = closing_time._date

GROUP BY TRN_TRANS.RTL_LOC_ID, _date, _hours
```

Comment: Trying to execute the query produces the following SQL error:Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: falta palavra chave
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Well I'm sorry but the I know not much about Oracle. The concept of this query works. I tested it and it give a result in the form: 2390, 14.10.01, 11:20:39; 2390, 14.10.02, 08:03:45 and so on. It groups by id and date. I hope someone can help you with converting it to Oracle or has an other/better solution. Good Luck! Sorry I can't help any further.